# C# Linked list with multiple branches

Tags: c#, list, linked-list

I have been trying to complete my assignment, but I don't know how to create a linked list with multiple branches. I have extracted my data, narrowed it down and then stored it in a List.

```
List<Route> routes = new List<Route>();
```

Route contains two string variables: *city1Name* and *city2Name*.

```
Route route = new Route("FirstCity", "SecondCity");
```

This means that there's a route between **FirstCity** and **SecondCity**. Each city can have multiple routes to other cities.

**Could someone show me how to store the this data in a linked list?**
I understand what a linked list is and I think I could fetch the multiple possible route data using *foreach* afterwards, but I was not able to write an algorithm for that. :(

Comment: you are looking for a node graph https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379574(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Osvaldon see my answer below, I've added a snippet to find possible route from one city to other. But that doesn't find shortest path. See demo here https://repl.it/CBgX/3

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`List<T>.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) to append any item of type `T` while T can be any .NET compliant data type. In your case `T` is `Route`. So, you can append any value that can be implicitly convertible to `Route`

```
routes.Add(route);
```

Further, In .NET `List<T>` is not a link list. [`List<T>` is implemented using Array internally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx). Link List implementation in .NET is [`LinkList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx)

**EDIT**

Here is a very simple implementation to find path form one city to other.

```
static bool TryFindPath(List<Route> routes, string from, string to, int maxDepth) {

    if (maxDepth <= 0) // To prevent StackOverFlowException
        return false;

    // Find all the routes with starting point == `from`
    var startingPoints = Routes.Where(r => r.From == from).ToArray();
    if (startingPoints.Length == 0) // No such route exists
        return false;

    // See if any of route directly leads to `to`
    var matchingRoute = startingPoints.Where(r => r.To == to).FirstOrDefault();
    if (matchingRoute != null) {
        routes.Add(matchingRoute); // If so, we found that
        return true;
    }


    // We are stepping into next level, decrease maxDepth by one
    maxDepth -= 1;

    // Otherwise iterate through all starting points and find path from
    // that specific city refered by to our destination 
    foreach (var route in startingPoints) {

        // Clone `routes`
        var thisRoutes = new List<Route>(routes);
        thisRoutes.Add(route);

        if (TryFindPath(thisRoutes, route.To, to, maxDepth)) {

            // Copy all newly added routes in `thisRoutes` to original `routes` 
            for (var i = routes.Count; i < thisRoutes.Count; i++) {
                routes.Add(thisRoutes[i]);
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I'm supposing following definition of Route class

```
class Route {

    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }

    public Route(string from, string to) {
        From = from;
        To = to;
    }
}
```

You can find working demo [here](https://repl.it/CBgX/3)

Comment: I am grateful for the work you've done and I will add you reputation for that. But what I actually need is to create a multi-way linked list from the data stored in an array List<Route> routes = new List<Route>(); because it's the primary requirement for the assigment :( I will add an example of what a one-way linked list looks like or so I was told.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Route> routes = new List<Route>();
Route route = new Route("FirstCity", "SecondCity");
routes.Add(route);

foreach (oneRoute in routes)
{
     // The other work you're interested in doing
     // oneRoute represents each single route one at a time.
}
```